# StretchBlt function returns a weird white dots bitmap

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi, stretchblt

I'm trying to write a simple bitmap resizer application using window API, this is my bitmap resizer function:

```cpp
BOOL ResizeBitmap(HBITMAP hOriginalBitmap, const char resizedFilename[], BitmapAngle NewAngle, BitmapAngle BmAngle){
    HDC hdcSrc = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
    HGDIOBJ originalObject = SelectObject(hdcSrc, hOriginalBitmap);

    HDC hdcDest = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
    HBITMAP hNewBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcDest, NewAngle.Width, NewAngle.Height);

    if (!hNewBitmap) {
        GetErrorCode("CreateCompatibleBitmap");
        ExitProcess(0);
    }

    SelectObject(hdcDest, hNewBitmap);

    // Set the stretch mode to HALFTONE for better quality
    SetStretchBltMode(hdcDest, HALFTONE);
    SetBrushOrgEx(hdcDest, 0, 0, NULL);

    // Use StretchBlt to resize the original bitmap onto the new bitmap
    StretchBlt(hdcDest, 0, 0, NewAngle.Width, NewAngle.Height,
               hdcSrc, 0, 0, BmAngle.Width, BmAngle.Height,
               SRCCOPY);

    // BitBlt(hdcDest, 0, 0, NewAngle.Width, NewAngle.Height, hdcSrc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    // Save the resized bitmap to a file
    SaveBitmapToFile(hNewBitmap, NewAngle, resizedFilename);

    SelectObject(hdcSrc, originalObject);
    DeleteDC(hdcSrc);
    DeleteDC(hdcDest);
    DeleteObject(hNewBitmap);

    return TRUE;
}
```

this is my SaveBitmapToFile function:

```cpp
BOOL SaveBitmapToFile(HBITMAP hBitMap, BitmapAngle Angle, const char NewFileName[]) {
    HDC hDevice = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
    SelectObject(hDevice, hBitMap);

    BITMAPINFOHEADER BitmapInfoHeader = GetBitmapInfoHeader(Angle);
    BITMAPFILEHEADER BitMapFileHeader = GetBitmapFileHeader(Angle);

    DWORD AllocatedSize = Angle.Width * Angle.Height * 3;  // Assuming 24 bits per pixel

    BYTE* BitmapData = VirtualAlloc(NULL, AllocatedSize, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);

    int Result = GetDIBits(hDevice, hBitMap, 0, Angle.Height, BitmapData, (BITMAPINFO*)&BitmapInfoHeader, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    if (!Result) {
        GetErrorCode("GetDIBits");
        ExitProcess(0);
    }

    HANDLE hFile = CreateFileA(NewFileName, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
    if (!hFile) {
        GetErrorCode("CreateFileA");
        ExitProcess(0);
    }

    // Write headers and bitmap data to the file
    WriteFile(hFile, &BitMapFileHeader, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), NULL, NULL);
    WriteFile(hFile, &BitmapInfoHeader, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), NULL, NULL);
    WriteFile(hFile, BitmapData, AllocatedSize, NULL, NULL);

    CloseHandle(hFile);

    VirtualFree(BitmapData, AllocatedSize, MEM_RELEASE);

    DeleteDC(hDevice);

    if (!GetLastError()) {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        GetErrorCode("SaveBitmapToFile");
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

However, the result bitmap file looks really weird, it just a bitmap with white dot:

[The input bitmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Io7hL.png)
[The Output bitmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WM0hn.png)

The SaveBitmapToFile function works really fine, when i try to take a screenshot, so i think the problem is in ResizeBitmap function

This is my screenshot function, which works really fine.

```cpp
HBITMAP GetScreenBitmap() {
    HDC hdcScreen = GetDC(NULL);
    int screenWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
    int screenHeight = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);

    // Create a compatible memory DC using the screen DC
    HDC hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcScreen);

    // Create a compatible bitmap using the screen DC
    HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcScreen, screenWidth, screenHeight);

    // Select the bitmap into the memory DC
    SelectObject(hdcMem, hBitmap);

    // BitBlt to copy the contents of the screen to the memory DC
    BitBlt(hdcMem, 0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight, hdcScreen, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    // Release resources
    ReleaseDC(NULL, hdcScreen);
    DeleteDC(hdcMem);

    return hBitmap;
}

HBITMAP hCurrentScreen = GetScreenBitmap();
BitmapAngle BmAngle; BmAngle.Height = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN); BmAngle.Width = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
SaveBitmapToFile(hCurrentScreen, BmAngle, "TEST.bmp");
```

Comment: [`CreateCompatibleBitmap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createcompatiblebitmap): *"When a memory device context is created, it initially has a 1-by-1 monochrome bitmap selected into it. If this memory device context is used in `CreateCompatibleBitmap`, the bitmap that is created is a **monochrome** bitmap. To create a color bitmap, use the `HDC` that was used to create the memory device context \[...\]"*.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Just change the line 
`CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcDest, NewAngle.Width, NewAngle.Height);` 
To
`CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcSrc, NewAngle.Width, NewAngle.Height);`
Will solve the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Thank to @IInspectable

Just change the line
`CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcDest, NewAngle.Width, NewAngle.Height);`

To
`CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcSrc, NewAngle.Width, NewAngle.Height);`

Will solve the problem!

[resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createcompatiblebitmap)

Comment: That, by itself, will do nothing to solve the issue here. The crucial detail is the call to `SelectObject()` that replaces the *monochrome* bitmap in `hdcSrc` with whatever `hOriginalBitmap` represents. You can verify this by moving the `SelectObject()` call after the `CreateCompatibleBitmap()` call, and the issue resurfaces.